# UIScrollView does not scroll with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, autolayout

I can't make UIScrollView scroll vertically when using Autolayout, I've tried many suggestions. I've read Apple's [technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html) but even that doesn't seem to work with my pure auto layout approach.

Here is my simple code where I'm adding two UIView blocks1 & 2 in a container view. The container view itself is the only child of the UIScrollView as suggested by many references online. I set the heights of block 1 and 2 as 800 points each, but the scroll view won't scroll.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];


        // Test UIScrollView with Autolayout, scrolling should word

        UIView *mainView = self.view;

        UIScrollView* scrollView = [UIScrollView new];
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

        UIView* contentView = [UIView new];
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [scrollView addSubview:contentView];

        UIView* block1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
        block1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [block1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [contentView addSubview:block1];

        UIView* block2 = [[UIView alloc] init];
        block2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [block2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [contentView addSubview:block2];


        NSDictionary* viewDict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(mainView,scrollView, contentView, block1, block2);

        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict]];
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict]];


        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[contentView(==mainView)]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict]];
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[contentView(==mainView)]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict]];


        [contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[block1(==300)]" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict]];
        [contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[block1(==800)]" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict]];

        [contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[block2(==300)]" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict]];
        [contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-810-[block2(==800)]" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict]];

}
```

Comment: for one, I would define your constraints on the blocks y-axis as `V:|[block1(==800)]-10-[block2(==block1)]|`. As for the scrolling, I believe you need to define the frame of something, somewhere. The frame/bounds of a scroll view is (0,0,0,0), and even if you add the content view in the scroll view, and the blocks in the content view, those bounds can still be (0,0,0,0) and still satisfy the constraints you list... it just adds the blocks on top of a UIView with a size of (0,0). I would nslog the bounds of your content view and scroll view to confirm

Comment: I think that UIScrollView is the worst control to get working with Auto Layout. The key difficulty, as explained in the technical note, is the requirement that things contained in the scroll view not depend on the scroll view for their size. In other words, it doesn't behave like a normal container view where the things inside can expand or shrink with their container (and thus, device size). The example they give uses an image view which has intrinsic size. I don't think this is very helpful for real-life applications.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your code, It seems that the size of you content view will be of same size as UIView.

e.g. : IF Device screen height is 568 then your content view size will be 568, and you are set your **block2** at y position = 180.

**Your Code:**

```
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[contentView(==mainView)]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict]];
```

**change:**

```
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[contentView(2000)]|” options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict]];
```

Hope it solves your problem if any further query please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is make a scroll view work with auto layouts, you can try this.
http://natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes in your code

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[contentView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict]];

[contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-810-[block2(==800)]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict]];
```

Hope this helps